# Florida Building codes concerning T-Post Fences

Tags: fence, permitting

I've got a vacant lot in Lake Placid Florida ( *Highland county* ) just north of lake Okeechobee.  The lot is not on a paved street and is a good mile from a paved street and houses.  It gets no mail or garbage service.  There are no power lines or water lines.  I camped on the lot for three nights and saw nobody drive or walk by while there.

It was a cheap lot and i don't want to spend any more money on it for a survey or permits. I have no plans to build. I'd like to install ( *no concrete* ) some 10 t-post well inside my lot lines and run some 12ga steel lines as perimeter to keep ATVs out and  help grow some vines and thorn hedges.

If I ask, the county might want a permit and subsequently a survey.  Do I need a permit ?  What could go wrong if i just do it ?

Ive read if you get caught the permit cost x 2, but is this even a permanent fence ?

What about barbed-wire lines and Liability issues ?

Comment: If ATV's are an issue, any fencing  better be legal and signs posted. Someone gets injured and the lawyers will be swarming in.

Comment: Didn't you get a survey when you bought it?

Comment: no survey.  cheap lot.  some signs are already posted.  no ATVs through the lots themselves. pretty wooded.

Comment: We can not advise you on legal matters. If you put up wire you need to have it clearly marked with bright streamers so people on ATV's do not behead themselves on your fence. You will also need clearly visible no trespassing signs.

Comment: You probably don't need a survey if the corners are clearly marked (so you know where the lines are.) Given clearly marked corners, it's pretty simple to throw up some temporary posts and use an inexpensive string to help you establish where the lines "really are" between the corners. If the corners are not clearly marked or you cannot FIND the corner markers, you pretty much need a survey (and should have had one in the transaction - otherwise you really have no idea if "where you think the lines are" that you are "fencing inside of" has any relationship to what you actually bought.)

Comment: "What you need to do" is very much a LAHJ question, (so you need local advice, not global advice that may differ from local practices/laws) and it tends to be one where forgiveness costs a lot more than permission, in general.

Comment: No clear corners, no survey. Lot was sold as is.  I've been able to identify the 4 corners using GPS and some landmark visible in Satelite shots from county maps on 3 or 4 visits.  Not looking to do anything that can't be quickly undone and plan to step a foot or two into the lot for good measure.   As for local advice, want to be careful and no neighbors, but i think the county has a lot more to worry about than my T-post fence.  the forgiveness cost is only a double payment on permit from what i read.

Comment: @Ecnerwal,  I'm not sure that in Florida when they platted the lots that they always stake down rods in the corners.  I've been going from county maps that product GPS coordinates.  At this time not too worried about losing a foot here or there. I just want to camp there with some security and be able to leave things tied down well inside the lot.

Comment: On the one hand selective availability has been turned off for decades - on the other hand, your phone is not a survey-grade GPS, so pinpoint accuracy (or reproducibility) may not be very likely. But if you're going to give it 10 feet of windage you'll probably end up on your own land if the maps you are starting from are accurate. Try checking a few hard landmarks (or actual benchmarks) against what your phone (or chosen GPS unit) says. It would be highly unusual to not have physical markers (may or may not be rods) at the physical corners.

Comment: I have not heard of t posts needing a permit but they are easy In (easy out if needed) and I would not put concrete around them. there should be some monuments that identify the boundaries even if not on your property get the plot maps you may be surprised to find there are markers or monuments regularly located in the area if not at at least 1 point on the property. Don’t guess just ask about a fence before putting one up ignorance of a law is not a defense if you put something up that requires a permit so it is best to know the requirements if any.

Comment: @Ecnrwal.  I did exactly that a few months ago but much further south.  and was able to confirm (at least on that day) that my phone was reporting GPS coordinates down to the a few feet! It was impressive to know this.  There are no neighbors and nothing around me and the plan is to grow a wild, natural and thorny perimeter fence in and around the T-Post cable fence.  later this year when Google Earth updates I will be able to adjust the T-Posts as needed and possibly eventually remove/repurposed  them.